# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). on react-redux app calling a rails API with axios

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, axios

I am trying to register an user in my react-redux app from a rails API  and store it in localStorage, so I can use it to log in, and get a post 404 error. I don't understand why, as I am using the right API endpoint:(POST   /api/v1/register/:name/:email/:password(.:format))

here is the code for the registerSlice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  logged_in: false,
  error: null,
};

export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/register',
  ({
    email, name, password, setLoading,
  }) => {
    const result = axios
      .post(
        `https://dreamcars2.onrender.com/api/v1/register/${name}/${email}/${password}`,
      )
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        return {
          user: null,
          logged_in: false,
          error: error.response.data.error,
        };
      });
    return result;
  },
);
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/login',
  ({ email, password, setLoading }) => {
    const result = axios
      .get(`https://dreamcars2.onrender.com/api/v1/login/${email}/${password}`)
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        window.location.reload();
        return {
          user: true,
          logged_in: true,
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        return {
          user: null,
          logged_in: false,
          error: error.response.data.error,
        };
      });
    return result;
  },
);

export const registerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'register',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    checkUser: () => {
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (user) {
        return user;
      }
      return {
        user,
        logged_in: false,
        error: null,
      };
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [register.fulfilled]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      user: action.payload.user,
      logged_in: action.payload.logged_in,
      error: action.payload.error,
    }),
    [register.rejected]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      error: action.payload,
    }),
    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      user: action.payload.user,
      logged_in: action.payload.logged_in,
      error: action.payload.error,
    }),
    [login.rejected]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      error: action.payload,
    }),
  },
});

export default registerSlice.reducer;
export const { checkUser } = registerSlice.actions;
```

here is the users_controller code:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authorize_request, except: %i[index create]
  # before_action :find_user, except: %i[create index]

  ALLOWED_DATA = %(name email password).freeze

  # GET /users
  def index
    users = User.all
    render json: users, status: :ok
  end

  # GET /users/:id
  def show
    render json: @user, status: :ok
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    data = json_payload.select { |allow| ALLOWED_DATA.include?(allow) && allow != 'role' }
    return render json: { error: 'Empty body. Could not create user.' }, status: :unprocessable_entity if data.blank?

    user = User.new(data)
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'Could not create user.' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/:id
  def update
    if current_user.is? :admin
      data = json_payload.select { |allow| ALLOWED_DATA.include?(allow) }
      return render json: { error: 'Empty body. Could not update user.' }, status: :unprocessable_entity if data.blank?

      if @user.update(data)
        render json: @user, status: :ok
      else
        render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: { error: 'Unauthorized.' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/:id
  def destroy
    if current_user.is? :admin
      @user.destroy
      render json: @user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'Unauthorized.' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def register
    if User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
      render json: { error: 'Useremail already exists! please choose another one.' }, status: :not_acceptable
    else
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      @user.email = @user.email.downcase
      if @user.save
        render json: { user: @user, logged_in: true }, status: :created
      else
        render json: { error: 'There was an error, please try again!' }, status: :internal_server_error
      end
    end
  end

  def login
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if @user
      render json: { user: @user, logged_in: true }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'email is invalid.' }, status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = User.find_by_id!(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render json: { errors: 'User not found' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

here is the user controller:

```
def register
    if User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
      render json: { error: 'UserEmail already exists! please choose another one.' }, status: :not_acceptable
    else
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      @user.email = @user.email.downcase
      if @user.save
        render json: { user: @user, logged_in: true }, status: :created
      else
        render json: { error: 'There was an error, please try again!' }, status: :internal_server_error
      end
    end
  end

  def login
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if @user
      render json: { user: @user, logged_in: true }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'email is invalid.' }, status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a register controller set up in your api?

Comment: yes, @dbugger. in users_controller:

Comment: ```def register
    if User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
      render json: { error: 'Useremail already exists! please choose another one.' }, status: :not_acceptable
    else
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      @user.email = @user.email.downcase
      if @user.save
        render json: { user: @user, logged_in: true }, status: :created
      else
        render json: { error: 'There was an error, please try again!' }, status: :internal_server_error
      end
    end
  end

Comment: update the question -- don't add to the comments

Comment: 'Useremail already exists! please choose another one.'

Comment: If you are getting a response from the server you don't expect then you should probably include the server code with the [mcve]. We can't address issues in code we can't see. This doesn't appear to be an issue with the client-side Redux.

Comment: Add the relevant routes from your `rails routes` output.

Comment: Actually, I'm closing this - you already had a thread going about this.